# How to parameterise Postgresql Interval for TimescaleDB `time_bucket` function with JPQL, Spring Data Repositories and Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpql, jpa-2.1, timescaledb

I am using Spring Data JPA (with Hibernate underneath, JPA 2.1) with TimescaleDB extension on PostgreSQL 13, and wish to use the [`time_bucket`](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/analytics/time_bucket/#time-bucket) function. This takes the `bucket_width` which is an `INTERVAL` and `time` which is the `TIMESTAMP` column of the data.

I want to put this in a Spring Data Repository and want to use a JPQL `@Query` to extract the data into a projection that represents the aggregate counts, averages etc. for the returned time buckets. I don't want to use a native query, because I want to join with some other tables, and populate their entities automatically.

I registered the `time_bucket` function to the `PostgisPG95Dialect` I am extending, like this:

```
public class CustomPostgresqlDialect extends PostgisPG95Dialect {

    public CustomPostgresqlDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerFunction("time_bucket", new StandardSQLFunction("time_bucket", new OffsetDateTimeType()));
    }
}
```

If the `bucket_width` is hardcoded, all this works fine. But I want the `bucket_width` to be a parameter of the query method.

The following works fine:

```
 @Query("select sys as system, "
                  + "function('time_bucket', '10 mins', vt.ts) as startTime, "
                  + "count(vt) as total, avg(vt.speed) as avgSpeed "
                  + "from Data vt "
                  + "JOIN vt.system sys "
                  + "where sys.sysId = :sysId and "
                  + "function('time_bucket', '10 mins', vt.ts)  between :from and :to "
                  + "group by system, startTime "
                  + "order by startTime")
  List<SummaryAggregate> getSummaryData(
          @Param("sysId") String sysId,
          @Param("from") OffsetDateTime from,
          @Param("to") OffsetDateTime to);
```

But when I try to parameterise the interval I can't get it to work. I tried passing the interval as a string, since that is how it is being written in the hardcoded version:

```
 @Query("select sys as system, "
                  + "function('time_bucket', :grouping, vt.ts) as startTime, "
                  + "count(vt) as total, avg(vt.speed) as avgSpeed "
                  + "from Data vt "
                  + "JOIN vt.system sys "
                  + "where sys.sysId = :sysId and "
                  + "function('time_bucket', :grouping, vt.ts)  between :from and :to "
                  + "group by system, startTime "
                  + "order by startTime")
  List<SummaryAggregate> getSummaryData(
          @Param("sysId") String sysId,
          @Param("from") OffsetDateTime from,
          @Param("to") OffsetDateTime to,
          @Param("grouping") String grouping);
```

where `grouping` is passed a value like `10 mins`.

But for this I get this error:

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
ERROR: function time_bucket(character varying, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 61
```

I then tried to change it to a `Duration`, since [Hibernate translates `Duration` to PostgreSQL Interval types](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-postgresql-interval-java-duration-hibernate/)

```
 @Query("select sys as system, "
                  + "function('time_bucket', :grouping, vt.ts) as startTime, "
                  + "count(vt) as total, avg(vt.speed) as avgSpeed "
                  + "from Data vt "
                  + "JOIN vt.system sys "
                  + "where sys.sysId = :sysId and "
                  + "function('time_bucket', :grouping, vt.ts)  between :from and :to "
                  + "group by system, startTime "
                  + "order by startTime")
  List<SummaryAggregate> getSummaryData(
          @Param("sysId") String sysId,
          @Param("from") OffsetDateTime from,
          @Param("to") OffsetDateTime to,
          @Param("grouping") Duration grouping);
```

But I still got the same error, this time it is thinking that the Duration is a `bigint` not an `Interval`.

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
ERROR: function time_bucket(bigint, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 61
```

Is there a way to parameterise an `Interval` using JPQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, but you will have to register a custom function for this purpose because you can't cast to an arbitrary SQL type.

```
public class CastInterval implements SQLFunction {

    @Override
    public boolean hasArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getReturnType(Type firstArgumentType, Mapping mapping) throws QueryException {
        return firstArgumentType;
    }

    @Override
    public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {
        return "cast(" + args.get(0) + " as interval)";
    }
}
```

You will have to register the function within the Dialect.

So if the Dialect is being extended as indicated, this would be done with something like:

```
 this.registerFunction("castInterval", new CastInterval());
```

Then you can use it like this: `function('time_bucket', castInterval(:grouping), vt.ts)`

Comment: Any idea how I can use that in a JPQL `function` though? I tried `"function('time_bucket', castInterval(:grouping), vt.ts)` and it didn't work. (It gave an error 
`antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: vt`, so I presume that is not valid syntax.)

Comment: Not sure where the exception comes from, but this is valid syntax.

Comment: You're right... everything works... thanks!